# How selenium-webdriver can wait XHR answer?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xmlhttprequest, automated-tests

I have content tag with some data(data every time is new) in page, what updated after click some button.
On backend server sent XHR and i wanna wait answer and continue.
Need check what data i get from backend server, but i can't compare first initialized data with new data, because i don't know initialized data and new data.

I think can wrote in variable - initialized data and new data.
Then i will compare with data in page, until data not changed. But if it will be same data, this situiation can be bad, test will be wrong.

Try this:

```
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            return ((Long)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // no jQuery present
            return true;
        }
    }
};

ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("console.log(document.readyState); return document.readyState")
                        .toString().equals("complete");
            }
        };
```

I geting "complete" in console, before get answer from backend server.

Answer (score 0):

Need use **refreshed**

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions));

From documentation https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

Wrapper for a condition, which allows for elements to update by redrawing. This works around the problem of conditions which have two parts: find an element and then check for some condition on it. For these conditions it is possible that an element is located and then subsequently it is redrawn on the client. When this happens a StaleElementReferenceException is thrown when the second part of the condition is checked.